# Настройка xfce4-terminal

Tags: консоль, xfce4-terminal, .bashrc

Cвежий xfce4-terminal v0.8.9.1 на аналоге Ubuntu 20.04. - LinuxLite 5.2

```
~$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

после какой-то команды отобразило:
[image: term]

при этом
[image: term]

Вопросы:

1. Что означает "1" и "130" на верхней картинке? ( у меня нет директорий с такими названиями) 130 - это какой-то номер предыдущей команды history? как-то связано с pipe предыдущей команды? а "1" ?
2. Как сделать чтобы подобные числа не отображались, оставить только привычное отображение вывода, но не отключая нового графического отображения ?

при этом:
в настройках конфига терминала `'/ home/ex/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc'` я не смог обнаружить данной настройки.

B .bashrc отсутствует $PS1, есть два цикла:

```
# enable bash completion in interactive shells
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

...

```
# Powerline
if [ -f /usr/share/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh ]; then
    source /usr/share/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh
fi
```

В содержании `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` не обнаружил упоминания $PS1, он достаточно объемен и не знаю, есть ли смысл его выкладывать, а вот если закомментировать в .bashrc второй цикл с `'/usr/share/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh'`

то возвращает привычное простое текстовое:

```
~$ echo $PS1
${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
```

*однако тогда исчезает цветное графическое отображение приглашения.*

---

содержание powerline.sh

```
cat /usr/share/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh
_powerline_columns_fallback() {
    if which stty &>/dev/null ; then
        local cols="$(stty size 2>/dev/null)"
        if ! test -z "$cols" ; then
            echo "${cols#* }"
            return 0
        fi
    fi
    echo 0
    return 0
}

_powerline_tmux_pane() {
    echo "${TMUX_PANE:-`TMUX="$_POWERLINE_TMUX" tmux display -p "#D"`}" | \
        tr -d ' %'
}

_powerline_tmux_setenv() {
    TMUX="$_POWERLINE_TMUX" tmux setenv -g TMUX_"$1"_`_powerline_tmux_pane` "$2"
    TMUX="$_POWERLINE_TMUX" tmux refresh -S
}

_powerline_tmux_set_pwd() {
    if test "$_POWERLINE_SAVED_PWD" != "$PWD" ; then
        _POWERLINE_SAVED_PWD="$PWD"
        _powerline_tmux_setenv PWD "$PWD"
    fi
}

_powerline_return() {
    return $1
}

_POWERLINE_HAS_PIPESTATUS="$(
    _powerline_return 0 | _powerline_return 43
    test "${PIPESTATUS[*]}" = "0 43"
    echo "$?"
)"

_powerline_has_pipestatus() {
    return $_POWERLINE_HAS_PIPESTATUS
}

_powerline_status_wrapper() {
    local last_exit_code=$? last_pipe_status=( "${PIPESTATUS[@]}" )

    if ! _powerline_has_pipestatus \
       || test "${#last_pipe_status[@]}" -eq "0" \
       || test "$last_exit_code" != "${last_pipe_status[$(( ${#last_pipe_status[@]} - 1 ))]}" ; then
        last_pipe_status=()
    fi
    "$@" $last_exit_code "${last_pipe_status[*]}"
    return $last_exit_code
}

_powerline_add_status_wrapped_command() {
    local action="$1" ; shift
    local cmd="$1" ; shift
    full_cmd="_powerline_status_wrapper $cmd"
    if test "$action" = "append" ; then
        PROMPT_COMMAND="$PROMPT_COMMAND"$'\n'"$full_cmd"
    else
        PROMPT_COMMAND="$full_cmd"$'\n'"$PROMPT_COMMAND"
    fi
}

_powerline_tmux_set_columns() {
    _powerline_tmux_setenv COLUMNS "${COLUMNS:-`_powerline_columns_fallback`}"
}

_powerline_init_tmux_support() {
    if test -n "$TMUX" && tmux refresh -S &>/dev/null ; then
        # TMUX variable may be unset to create new tmux session inside this one
        _POWERLINE_TMUX="$TMUX"

        trap '_powerline_tmux_set_columns' WINCH
        _powerline_tmux_set_columns

        test "$PROMPT_COMMAND" != "${PROMPT_COMMAND/_powerline_tmux_set_pwd}" \
            || _powerline_add_status_wrapped_command append _powerline_tmux_set_pwd
    fi
}

_powerline_local_prompt() {
    # Arguments:
    # 1: side
    # 2: renderer_module arg
    # 3: last_exit_code
    # 4: last_pipe_status
    # 5: jobnum
    # 6: local theme
    "$POWERLINE_COMMAND" $POWERLINE_COMMAND_ARGS shell $1 \
        $2 \
        --last-exit-code=$3 \
        --last-pipe-status="$4" \
        --jobnum=$5 \
        --renderer-arg="client_id=$$" \
        --renderer-arg="local_theme=$6"
}

_powerline_prompt() {
    # Arguments:
    # 1: side
    # 2: last_exit_code
    # 3: last_pipe_status
    # 4: jobnum
    "$POWERLINE_COMMAND" $POWERLINE_COMMAND_ARGS shell $1 \
        --width="${COLUMNS:-$(_powerline_columns_fallback)}" \
        -r.bash \
        --last-exit-code=$2 \
        --last-pipe-status="$3" \
        --jobnum=$4 \
        --renderer-arg="client_id=$$"
}

_powerline_set_prompt() {
    local last_exit_code=$1 ; shift
    local last_pipe_status=$1 ; shift
    local jobnum="$(jobs -p|wc -l)"
    PS1="$(_powerline_prompt aboveleft $last_exit_code "$last_pipe_status" $jobnum)"
    if test -n "$POWERLINE_SHELL_CONTINUATION$POWERLINE_BASH_CONTINUATION" ; then
        PS2="$(_powerline_local_prompt left -r.bash $last_exit_code "$last_pipe_status" $jobnum continuation)"
    fi
    if test -n "$POWERLINE_SHELL_SELECT$POWERLINE_BASH_SELECT" ; then
        PS3="$(_powerline_local_prompt left '' $last_exit_code "$last_pipe_status" $jobnum select)"
    fi
}

_powerline_setup_prompt() {
    VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1
    if test -z "${POWERLINE_COMMAND}" ; then
        POWERLINE_COMMAND="$("$POWERLINE_CONFIG_COMMAND" shell command)"
    fi
    test "$PROMPT_COMMAND" != "${PROMPT_COMMAND%_powerline_set_prompt*}" \
        || _powerline_add_status_wrapped_command prepend _powerline_set_prompt
    PS2="$(_powerline_local_prompt left -r.bash 0 0 0 continuation)"
    PS3="$(_powerline_local_prompt left '' 0 0 0 select)"
}

if test -z "${POWERLINE_CONFIG_COMMAND}" ; then
    if which powerline-config >/dev/null ; then
        POWERLINE_CONFIG_COMMAND=powerline-config
    else
        POWERLINE_CONFIG_COMMAND="$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")/../../../scripts/powerline-config"
    fi
fi

if "${POWERLINE_CONFIG_COMMAND}" shell --shell=bash uses prompt ; then
    _powerline_setup_prompt
fi
if "${POWERLINE_CONFIG_COMMAND}" shell --shell=bash uses tmux ; then
    _powerline_init_tmux_support
fi
```

Comment: Powerline - это и есть ваш PROMPT

Comment: не знаю точно что такое 130 и 1, вероятно, это коды завершения предыдущих запущенных команд.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете выключить Powerline если не пользуетесь его функционалом. Чтобы сохранить внешний вид PROMPT, вам надо добавить в `.bashrc` следующий  скрипт. Весь функционал работает "из коробки" (без настроек). Вы можете поменять что-то, что-то вырезать, что-то добавить. Свой PROMPT я составлял по этой статье: [Bash/Prompt customization](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)/Prompt_customization_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)).

[image: Powerline PROMPT]

```
#
# Fallback prompt
#


PS1='\u@\h \W\$ '

PROMPT_COMMAND=__UPDATE_PROMPT

#
# Prompt palete
#
#   0  Success color
#   1  Failed color
#   2  Return color
#   3  Muted color
#   4  User fg color
#   5  User bg color
#   6  Host fg color
#   7  Host bg color
#   8  CWD fg color
#   9  CWD bg color
#  10  RootUser fg color
#  11  RootUser bg color
#
#
#                 0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11
PROMPT_PALETTE=( 32 196   7 238 255  60 232  66 232 208 255 196 )
PROMPT_PALETTE=( 32 196   7 238 232  38 255  32 255  24 255 196 )
PROMPT_PALETTE=( 32 196   7 238 232 225 232  77 232 227 '231;1' 196 )
# PROMPT_PALETTE=( 32 196   7 238 232  38 255  32 255  24 255 196 )

__UPDATE_PROMPT(){
    local _R=$? PP=( ${PROMPT_PALETTE[*]} )
  { [[ -v MC_SID ]] || [[ $TERM == linux ]];} && return
  RE='\[\e[0m\]'  BO='\[\e[1m\]'  INV='\[\e[7m\]' NL='\\n' 
  FG='\[\e[38;5;' BG='\[\e[48;5;' M='m\]'
  OK=$RE$FG${PP[0]:-32}$M"\\xe2\\x9c\\x85"$RE$NL
  ER='\[\e[$(($COLUMNS-5))G\]'$FG${PP[2]:-7}$M$(printf %3d\  $_R)
  ED=$RE$FG${PP[1]:-196}$M"\\xe2\\x9c\\x95"$RE$NL
  OF='\[\e[1A\]\[\e[$(($COLUMNS-1))G\]' DT='\D{%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z}' 
  AL="\\xee\\x82\\xb2" AR="\\xee\\x82\\xb0" DO='\[\e[$(($COLUMNS-27))G\]'
  DE=$DO$FG${PP[3]:-238}$M'E: '$DT$RE$NL
  DS=$DO$FG${PP[3]:-238}$M'S: '$DT$RE$NL
  [[ $_R -eq 0 ]] && RL=$OF$OK || RL=$OF$ER$ED
  [[ $UID -eq 0 ]] && { UB="${PP[11]:-196}"; UF="${PP[10]:-255}"; } ||
      { UB="${PP[5]:-60}"; UF="${PP[4]:-255}"; }
  UL=$BG$UB$M$FG$UF$M' $USER '$FG$UB$M
  HL=$BG${PP[7]:-66}$M$AR$FG${PP[6]:-232}$M' $HOSTNAME '$FG${PP[7]:-66}$M
  PL=$BG${PP[9]:-208}$M$AR$FG${PP[8]:-232}$M$BO' $CWD '$RE$FG${PP[9]:-208}$M
  CWD=`pwd` USER=`whoami` HOSTNAME=`hostname`
  [[ ${#CWD} -ge ${#HOME} ]] && [[ $HOME == ${CWD:0:${#HOME}} ]] &&
    [[ ${#HOME} -gt 1 ]] && CWD=\~${CWD:${#HOME}}
  [[ -z $COLUMNS ]] && PS1=$UL$HL$PL$AR$RE\  && PS0= && return
  THIRD=$(echo "$COLUMNS/3" | bc) DL="\\xe2\\x80\\xa6"
  PS2=$(echo -e $FG$UB$M$INV$AL$RE\ )
  [[ $(echo " $USER  $HOSTNAME  $CWD  " | wc -c) -gt $THIRD ]] &&
    HL='' && [[ $(echo " $USER  $CWD  " | wc -c) -gt $THIRD ]] &&
    UL=$FG$UB$M && [[ $(echo "  $CWD  " | wc -c) -gt $THIRD ]] &&
    CWD=$(echo $CWD | perl -pe 's/([^\/]{2})[^\/]{2,9}[\/]/\1'$DL'\//g') &&
    PS2=$(echo -e $FG${PP[9]:-208}$M$INV$AL$RE)
  PS1=$(echo -e $RL$DE$UL$HL$PL$AR$RE\ )
  PS0=$(echo -e $DS$RE )  
  export CWD USER HOSTNAME
}
```

Выглядит немного люто.  Цветовая палитра читается из массива  `${PROMPT_PALETTE}`.
Цвета перечислены в следующем порядке:

0. цвет успеха,
1. цвет провала,
2. цвет возвращаемого предыдущей командой значения,
3. цвет временных меток,
4. цвет шрифта *имени пользователя*,
5. цвет фона *имени пользователя*,
6. цвет шрифта *имени хоста*,
7. цвет фона *имени хоста*,
8. цвет шрифта *текущей директории*,
9. цвет фона *текущей директории*,
10. цвет шрифта *имени пользователя root*,
11. цвет фона *имени пользователя root*,

Коды цветов можно найти в [википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Коды символов можно найти тут:

- [стрелочки](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+2190),
- [технические символы](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+2300),
- [рисование окон и таблиц](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+2500),
- [блочные элементы](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+2580),
- [геометрические фигуры](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+25A0),
- [всякое разное](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+2600).

Еще отмечу хороший ресурс по BASH: [wiki.bash-hackers.org](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/doku.php)

Comment: Cпасибо!  Придется правда ряд переменных исключать для себя, но это уже понятнее.

Comment: Если хотите, я могу убрать все что не нужно.

Comment: Powerline на самом деле там гораздо глубже и мощнее. там он на 95% написан на python, там куча плагинов и все очень круто сделано за исключением одного - оно реально тормозит, то есть непосредственно потребляет много ресурсов CPU. Поэтому, его здорово использовать на настольных компах, а я предпочитаю работать на разных устройствах, в их числе и мобильники и одноплатники. Поэтому написал для себя легковесный PROMT который работает моментально и без зависимостей вроде python или чего-либо еще. Я практически всегда использую совместно с tmux.